# Python 3 - Can't call function under 'if' statement

Tags: python-3.x

I am just starting to learn Python and am creating a simple text adventure game. In a part of the game, you can die. And when you die I made it so dead = True. I also defined a function called dead() and made it only run if dead == True. The problem is the function dead() is not being called.

The function dead() is able to be called without the if statement. I also made dead global.

Where I make dead = True: (inside a while True loop, inside a different function)

```
            elif action == 'Suicide':
                dead = True
                del actions[0:3]
                print('\n' + name + ', not being able to take the stress, decided to end it all.')
                time.sleep(2)
                print('-Game Over-')
                break
```

The if statement:
    if dead == True:
        dead()

Expected results: After dead = True, and that loop is broken with 'break', I expected it to call the dead function due to dead = True.

Actual results: No error messages, just skips the if statement. (I know this because I put an empty input() after the if statement)

edit:
The dead function:

```py
    def dead(): # Restart function, when dead is True
        while True:
            try:
                print('\nWould you like to restart the game at your last checkpoint? (Y/N)')
                restartAns = input()
                if restartAns in ['Y','y']:
                    print('Restarting at last checkpoint..')
                    time.sleep(2)
                    if checkpoint == 0:
                        gameStart()
                elif restartAns in ['N','n']:
                    print('Game shutting down..')
                    time.sleep(3)
                    quit()
            except:
                print('An error has occurred. Please try again:')
                continue
            else:
                print('Please enter in either Y, or N:')
                continue
```

Code around the dead = True:

```py
    def gameStart(): # Beginning of Game
        global checkpoint
        global dead
        checkpoint = 0
        actions = ['Explore Forest', 'Suicide', 'Continue on road']
        while True:
            try:
                print('\nOkay, ' + name + '.' + ' What would you like to do? ' + str(actions))
                action = input()
                if action not in actions:
                    print('Please choose one of the options: ' + str(actions))
                    continue
                elif action == 'Explore Forest':
                    del actions[0:3]
                    print('\nYou wander into the forest and find an old abandoned mansion.')
                    time.sleep(2)
                    print('You walk up to the gates to find that it is closed tight.')
                    time.sleep(2)
                    break
                elif action == 'Suicide':
                    dead = True
                    del actions[0:3]
                    print('\n' + name + ', not being able to take the stress, decided to end it all.')
                    time.sleep(2)
                    print('-Game Over-')
                    break
                elif action == 'Continue on road':
                    actions.remove('Continue on road')
                    print('\nYou continue on the road.')
                    time.sleep(2)
                    print('After some walking, you realize that going straight will\nbring you nowhere, so you walk back to your car.')
                    time.sleep(4)
                    continue
            except:
                continue
```

Comment: Post the relevant code, you only showed that you're (probably) setting it to true

Comment: The actual code around the if else

Comment: Posted the code

Comment: You never call dead

Comment: At the end of that code (after the gameStart() ) I put if dead == True: dead()

Comment: Outside the while loop?

Comment: Yeah it's outside the while loop

Comment: Is it ever getting to that point in the code? Have you stepped through it with a debugger

Comment: `if dead == True: dead()` is a fundamentally broken statement.  If `dead` is indeed a function you can call, then it is obviously not equal to `True`.  You need to choose distinct names for the variable and the function.

Comment: @jasonharper That worked! Thank you so much. I changed the dead function to restartDead and that fixed it.